# how to show figure from linux terminal in python?

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, terminal

I use matplotlib in python 2.7 to display figures. It works fine in spyder env but when trying from terminal nothing happens.

Using code:

```
py.plot(x)    
py.show()
```

where is the tip?

---

Thanks darth kotic, I tested the following but it doesn't change anything.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp 
import matplotlib as mpl  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from pylab import *              

ion()                           
v=range(10)
plt.plot(v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spider automatically import several modules 
just type scientific in console and you will see:

```
This is a standard Python interpreter with preloaded tools for scientific 
computing and visualization. It tries to import the following modules:

>>> import numpy as np  # NumPy (multidimensional arrays, linear algebra, ...)
>>> import scipy as sp  # SciPy (signal and image processing library)
>>> import matplotlib as mpl         # Matplotlib (2D/3D plotting library)
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Matplotlib's pyplot: MATLAB-like syntax
>>> from pylab import *              # Matplotlib's pylab interface
>>> ion()                            # Turned on Matplotlib's interactive mode
```

Comment: point is: if you want to use this in linux terminal, you have to import this modules first.

Comment: thanks ! yes i have done with all imports but it's still the same

Comment: Ok. I tested it. window with plot disappear when interpreter exits so you need to add something like `raw_input("Press enter to continue")` at the end of your file and then it will work.